# div not showing with onmouseover

Tags: php, javascript, onmouseover

everything works perfect bar the div 'hidden-table' not showing, if i remove the 'style:display:none' then it shows the table with correct data so i know its working and i have tried the taking the popup out of the echo and displaying it separately just to see if it shows which it does.

seems the problem occurs only when its in the echo and seems centred around the 'onmousover'

full page code:

```
<html>




  <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class="center2">
  <tr>
  <td width='60'><img src="images/box_tl.png"></td>
  <td style="background: url(images/box_tm.png)" align="center"><img src="images/news.png"></td>
  <td width='25'><img src="images/box_tr.png"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="background: url(images/box_ml.png)"><h2>.</h2></td>
  <td style="background: url(images/box_mm.png)">


 <?php
include 'connect.php';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_img") or die(mysql_error());;

echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width'90%' id='1' class='tablesorter'><thead>";
echo "<tr> <th> </th> <th>Mob Name</th> <th>Id</th> <th>Health</th> <th>Body</th> <th>Effects</th> <th>Spawn</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {

 $mob_id = $row['mob_id'];
 $mob = $row['mob'];
 $body = $row['body'];
$mob_name = $row['mob_name'];
 $health = $row['health'];
 $level = $row['level'];

// Print out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr><td>";
echo "<img src='/testarea/include/mobs/$mob' />";
echo "</td><td>";
echo $mob_name;
echo "</td><td>";
echo $level;
echo "</td><td>";
echo $health;
echo "</td><td>";
echo 


"
<a onmouseover='popup($('#hidden-table').html(), 400);' href=''><img src='/testarea/include/mobs/dead/$body' /></a>
";

echo "

<div id='hidden-table' style='display:none;'>
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='center3'>
  <tr>
  <td width='14'><img src='images/info_tl.png'></td>
  <td style='background: url(images/info_tm.png)' align='center'></td>
  <td width='14'><img src='images/info_tr.png'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style='background: url(images/info_ml.png)'><h2>.</h2></td>
  <td style='background: url(images/info_mm.png)'>
";




$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_drop WHERE mob_name='$mob_name'") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width='250' id='2' class='tablesorter'><thead>";
 echo "<tr> <th> </th> <th>Item Name</th> <th>Qty</th></thead><tbody>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query2 )) {

$id = $row['id'];
$item_img = $row['item_img'];
$qty = $row['qty'];
$item_name = $row['item_name'];


// Print out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr><td width='50'>";
echo "<img src='/testarea/item/$item_img' />";
echo "</td><td width='150'>";
echo $item_name;
echo "</td><td width='50'>";
echo $qty;
echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table>";


echo "
  </td>
  <td style='background: url(images/info_mr.png)'><h2>.</h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width='14'><img src='images/info_bl.png'></td>
  <td style='background: url(images/info_bm.png)' align='center'><h2>.</h2></td>
  <td width='14'><img src='images/info_br.png'></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>"




;
echo "</td><td>";
echo "test";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "test";
echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table>";

?>




  </td>
  <td style="background: url(images/box_mr.png)"><h2>.</h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width='60'><img src="images/box_bl.png"></td>
  <td style="background: url(images/box_bm.png)" align="center"><h2>.</h2></td>
  <td width='25'><img src="images/box_br.png"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</html>
```

Comment: and the javascript function `popup` is defined where?

Comment: Your code is wrong on so many levels I find this offensive.

Comment: So if the problem is on the client, why are you including all this server-side code?

Comment: this page is currently being included into an index.php page which has all the .js and .css files popup is defined in popup.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inadvertently ending your `onmouseover` event when you try to reference your jQuery selector. The use of single quotes for different reasons is the reason. Try this instead:

```
function ShowPop()
{
    popup($('#hidden-table').html(), 400);
}

<a onmouseover='ShowPop()' href=''><img ..... /></a>
```

Comment: that managed to get the popup showing but now its showing the same data in the popup for each image on the different rows